# How can I make my bot ping a person with a command example: !eat @the user i want, the bot: @the user has been eated

Tags: discord.js

I want to do a command for example eat and i want the bot ping, here is an example :D

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
    const parts = message.content.split('');
    if (parts [0] == '!eat'){
        if (parts [1] == 'The member that i want to be pinged by the bot') {
            message.channel.send('The user that i pinged on command has been eated!')
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question. Don't post images of code.

Comment: Sure, sorry i am new on coding :D

Comment: Much better already!

Comment: Please, append `);` at the code ending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a few changes:

- I have added a global `prefix` variable, so that the prefix can easily be changed.
- I have added checks to make sure the function exits if the message was sent by a bot or doesn't start with the prefix.
- I have added some code to split the message into a command and arguments.
- I have replaced the `if` statement with a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement.

**I highly recommend that you read the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/), as it's very beginner friendly and will allow you to write even better code than in this answer. Much of the code in this answer is taken from the Discord.js guide.**

```js
const prefix = '!';

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/\s+/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  switch (command) {
    case 'eat':
      const member = message.mentions.members.first();
      if (!member) return message.reply('Could not find the mentioned user.');

      message.channel.send(`${member.user.username} has been eaten!`);
      break;
    default:
      message.reply(`The command \`${command}\` was not recognized`);
  }
});
```

## Explanation

The command prefix is set:

```js
const prefix = '!';
```

The function exits if the message was sent by a bot or doesn't start with the prefix:

```js
if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
```

The prefix is removed from the start of the message, and the message is split at all whitespace gaps:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/\s+/g);
```

The first argument is removed, converted to lowercase and stored in the `command` variable:

```js
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

The first mentioned user is found:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
```

If there is no mentioned user, a warning message is returned:

```js
if (!member) return message.reply('Could not find the mentioned user.');
```

A message is sent to the server saying *"[the user] has been eaten!"*:

```js
message.channel.send(`${member.user.username} has been eaten!`);
```

## References

- [`Message.mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions)

Comment: Thanks You so much, i'm new on coding and this is perfect :D

Answer (score 0):

<@${message.member.id}> That will ping the author of the message just use (``) and not (' ') and that will ping the author